# Same function throwing "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" in one page but not in the others

Tags: javascript, django, cors

I have a function to get zip code infos throughout my `django` website. The problem is that this function works perfectly in all pages except one. I'm using the same header to all pages.

```
var HttpClient = function () {
    this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
    anHttpRequest.send(null);
    }
}


function getZipCode(obj) {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.get("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + obj.value + "/json/", function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        //more code...
    })
}
```

In the problematic page I'm getting the famous "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error. I've reserached a lot about it, but couldn't find a proper solution when this problem appears in only one page. How can I make this work in all pages?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response from the problem URL? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools instead. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker The status code is 200...

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally: If you don't get that error on page A and you do get that error on page B, then either:

1. Page A and page B are on different origins. Their schemes are different (`http` vs. `https`, for instance), their host names are different (remember that `example.com` and `www.example.com` are different host names, leading to different origins), or their ports are different.
2. The target system at `viacep.com.br` actively decides whether to allow cross-origin calls based on its own rules, and chooses not to allow calls from page B's URL (by not sending back the necessary headers) even though it allows them from other pages on the same origin. That's something a system *can* do, but in practice rarely *does* do.

So assuming #1, what's different about page B in the same site? Some things it could be are:

- If the page with the problem is on `http` and all the others are on `https`, or vice-versa, and the origin allows cross-origin calls from one but not the other.
- If your pages are on `viacep.com.br` and the only page having the problem is on `https`. The call you're making is to `http://viacep.com.br` so other pages on `http://viacep.com.br` are same-origin (but a page on `https://viacep.com.br` is cross-origin).
- *(As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) pointed out)* The page with the problem is using a different host name, perhaps a subdomain or similar.

Comment: Sub domain page another possibility

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunately none of this looks to be the problem :(. 1) Their schemes are the same (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/<product_id>` (the problematic one) and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/`, for example); 2) I tried several others requests and the problem persists; 3) It's the same host name.

Comment: @MuriloSitonio - That argues for reason #2 above, I'm afraid. Might even be a bug in the target system.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed. But that would be a huuuuuuge coincidence if 10 or more (the number of requests I tried from different APIs) different systems do the same, right?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio - I don't know if I'd say "coincidence," but it's weird. :-) I was wondering if the other system doesn't like that URL for some reason -- because it has two segments, or ends with digits, or... (And I wouldn't be surprised if it were a bug in their CORS implementation.)